# How to solve “cannot call method 'down' of undefined” error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento

my coding is basically pop up a option box to user when they click buy now for option product(example:choose color).

When I loaded this js, it show:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'down' of undefined.

And when I click Buy now, it show:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addToCartHandle' of undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

    var urlAction = '<?php echo $this->getActionUrlBuy() ?>';
    var groupdeal = new GroupDeal('deal-ajaxcart-load-ajax','deal-ajaxcart-pop-up','deal-ajaxcart-content','','div[class="block block-cart"]',$$('.header').first().down('ul.links'),'ajaxcart'); //error here


    groupdeal.addToCartHandle = function(requestUrl, product_id, deal_id){
        groupdeal.url = urlAction+'?productId='+product_id;     
        $('deal-ajaxcart-load-ajax').show();        
        new Ajax.Request(urlAction,{
            method: 'get',          
            parameters: {productId:product_id, dealId:deal_id},
            onException: function (xhr, e){             
                $('deal-ajaxcart-load-ajax').hide();
                $('deal-ajaxcart-pop-up').hide();
                window.location.href = groupdeal.url;
            },
            onComplete: groupdeal.ajaxOnComplete
        });
    }
    groupdeal.ajaxOnComplete = function(xhr){       
        if (xhr.responseText.isJSON()){
            var response = xhr.responseText.evalJSON();
            groupdeal.popupContentWindow(response);

         }
    }

    function openPopup(product_id, deal_id){        
        groupdeal.addToCartHandle("",product_id, deal_id);//error here  
    }

    function closeDealAjaxPopup(){
        $('deal-ajaxcart-load-ajax').hide();
        $('deal-ajaxcart-pop-up').style.display = "none";
    }
    function ajaxMoreTemplateJs(){
        if ($('deal-ajaxcart-content').down(".paypal-logo")) $('ajaxcart-pop-up').down(".paypal-logo").hide();
        if ($('deal-ajaxcart-content').down(".add-to-links")) $('ajaxcart-pop-up').down(".add-to-links").hide();
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, when it run at old site, it work fine. But when move to new site(new skin, new function), it cant work. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: one reason could be `$` is not pointing to jQuery, in your browser console try `$ === jQuery`

Comment: Try to wrap your code into `$(function() { ... });` or put this script at the end of `body`.

Comment: Another reason could be that none of your jQuery selectors are targeting an id or class. Without seeing your HTML we can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

from a quick look I can say that the error you are getting from clicking buy now is because groupdeal never got defined from the first error. seems to me that you should look at the call for .header with the two $$ in front (should be one)for your answer, since it seems that particular method isnt computing from the other site. 2¢